# screen.blit() function executing even after pygame.quit() is used

Tags: pygame, display

I am making a basic pong game in pygame with a separate menu screen. I have figured out all the gameplay  (physics of ball,score system etc.).However, when i quit the game no matter from the menu screen or from the main game loop, i get this error:`pygame.error: display Surface quit`. I have seen all the posts about this error on stackoverflow, as well as other websites. I understand that the error is occuring because even after the `pygame.quit()` function, the next `screen.blit(player1,(player1x,player1y))` is being executed. Following is the my code :

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()


#screen 
screenw = 1000
screenh = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenw, screenh))
bg = pygame.image.load("bg.jpg")
dp = pygame.image.load("ping-pong.png")
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG")
pygame.display.set_icon(dp)

def main():

    # score
    font = pygame.font.Font('font.otf', 24)
    winfont = pygame.font.Font('font.otf', 50)
    score_value_p1 = 0
    scorexp1 = 10
    scoreyp1 = 0

    score_value_p2 = 0
    scorexp2 = screenw - 145
    scoreyp2 = 0

    #toss
    toss = random.choice([-1,1])

    #players
    def initial_bars():
        global player1,player1x,player1y,player1_change,player2,player2x,player2y,player2_change
        player1 = pygame.image.load("danda.png")
        player1 = pygame.transform.scale(player1,(25,128))
        player1x = 10
        player1y = 232
        player1_change = 0

        player2 = pygame.image.load("danda.png")
        player2 = pygame.transform.scale(player1,(25,128))
        player2x = 965
        player2y = 232
        player2_change = 0

    #ball
    def initial_ball():
        global ball,ballx,bally,ballx_change,bally_change
        ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
        ballx = 484 
        bally = 284
        ballx_change = 0.4*toss
        bally_change = 0.0

    initial_bars()
    initial_ball()

    global player1,player1x,player1y,player1_change,player2,player2x,player2y,player2_change,ball,ballx,bally,ballx_change,bally_change,running

    #functions
    def player1bar():
        screen.blit(player1,(player1x,player1y))

    def player2bar():
        screen.blit(player2,(player2x,player2y))

    def balll():
        screen.blit(ball,(ballx,bally))

    def show_score():
        scorep1 = font.render("Score : " + str(score_value_p1), True, (255, 50, 50))
        screen.blit(scorep1, (scorexp1 , scoreyp1))

        scorep2 = font.render("Score : " + str(score_value_p2), True, (255, 50, 50))
        screen.blit(scorep2, (scorexp2 , scoreyp2))

    #game window
    running = True
    while running:

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        pygame.draw.line(screen,(255,255,30),(499,0),(499,600), 10)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,(255,255,30),(500,300), 40, 10)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()

        # player1 movement
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s :
                    player1_change = 0.6
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player1_change = -0.6
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    player1_change = 0

        # player2 movement
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN :
                    player2_change = 0.6
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player2_change = -0.6
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player2_change = 0
        
        player1y += player1_change
        player2y += player2_change
        
        # player1 boundary
        if player1y <= 0:
            player1y = 0
        elif player1y >= 472:
            player1y = 472

    # player2 boundary
        if player2y <= 0:
            player2y = 0
        elif player2y >= 472:
            player2y = 472


        #ball move
        ballx += ballx_change
        bally += bally_change

        toss = random.choice([-1,1])
        if ballx < 35 and ballx > 30 and (player1y == bally or (player1y < bally and player1y > bally - 128) or (player1y > bally and player1y < bally + 32)):
            ballx_change *= -1
            if ballx_change < 1:
                ballx_change += 0.05
            bally_change = ballx_change*toss
            
        if ballx > 933 and ballx < 938 and (player2y == bally or (player2y < bally and player2y > bally - 128) or (player2y > bally and player2y < bally + 32)):
            ballx_change *= -1
            if ballx_change > -1:
                ballx_change -= 0.05
            bally_change = ballx_change*toss
            
        # ball boundary
        if bally < 0 or bally > screenh - 32:
            bally_change *= -1
        
        #score
        if ballx > screenw:
            score_value_p1 += 1
        if ballx < -32:
            score_value_p2 += 1

        #respawn
        if ballx > screenw or ballx < -32:
            initial_ball()    
            initial_bars()

        player1bar()
        player2bar()
        balll()
        show_score()

        #winner
        if score_value_p1 == 5:
            winner = winfont.render("The Winner is Player 1", True, (50, 255, 50))
            winner_rect = winner.get_rect(center=(screenw/2, screenh/2))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(winner_rect))
            screen.blit(winner, winner_rect)

        if score_value_p2 == 5:
            winner = winfont.render("The Winner is Player 2", True, (50, 255, 50))
            winner_rect = winner.get_rect(center=(screenw/2, screenh/2))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), pygame.Rect(winner_rect))
            screen.blit(winner, winner_rect)

        pygame.display.update()
        if score_value_p1 == 5 or score_value_p2 == 5:
            pygame.time.delay(2000)
            menu_screen()
        if ballx == 484 and bally == 284:
            pygame.time.delay(1250)
            ballx_change = 0.4*toss

def menu_screen():
    
    menufont = pygame.font.Font('font.otf', 50)
    tipfont = pygame.font.Font('font.otf', 30)
    running = True
    while running:

        screen.blit(bg,(0,0))
        title = menufont.render("Multiplayer Pong", True, (255, 255, 20))
        screen.blit(title, (220,70))
        tip = tipfont.render("Click Anywhere to Play", True, (50, 255, 50))
        screen.blit(tip, (275,500))
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                running = False

        pygame.display.update()

    main()
               
menu_screen()
```

I have tried methods like adding `break`,`pygame.quit()`,declaring `running` as a global variable. However, i have not been able to get rid of this problem. Can anyone please try o provide a solution for this problem. Following is the complete error i recieved :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\jaism\OneDrive\Desktop\Codes\Minor Project CSE\main.py", line 208, in <module>   
    menu_screen()
  File "c:\Users\jaism\OneDrive\Desktop\Codes\Minor Project CSE\main.py", line 206, in menu_screen
    main()
  File "c:\Users\jaism\OneDrive\Desktop\Codes\Minor Project CSE\main.py", line 158, in main
    player1bar()
  File "c:\Users\jaism\OneDrive\Desktop\Codes\Minor Project CSE\main.py", line 63, in player1bar
    screen.blit(player1,(player1x,player1y))
pygame.error: display Surface quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pygame.quit()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.quit) uninitialize all pygame modules that have previously been initialized. So you can't call any pygame API function after `pygame.quite()`. `pygame.quite()` must be the very last pygame function called after the application loop:

```py
def main():
    # [...]
    
    running = True
    while running:
        # [...]
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                # pygame.quit()                     <-- DELETE
        # [...]

def menu_screen():
    # [...]
    
    run_main = True
    running = True
    while running:
        # [...]
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                run_main = False
                # pygame.quit()                     <-- DELETE
       
        # [...]
     
    if run_main:
        main()

menu_screen()
pygame.quit()                                     # <-- INSERT
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I followed your steps and it is working flawlessly now :) From now on, I will keep it in mind to use `pygame.quit()` at the end.